# TSQL log - when users logged out / disconnected from server?

Tags: sql-server

So I've found from threads like this one: [Where are SQL Server connection attempts logged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769099/where-are-sql-server-connection-attempts-logged) that you can easily log loging, failed logins etc and the look them up using either of the following stored procedures.

```
EXEC xp_readerrorlog; 

EXEC xp_readerrorlog 2; 

EXEC sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Login failed'
```

The issus is that it does not seem to log when a user logs out or disconnects from the server. Here are the current settings (Server -> Properties -> Security):
[image]

So the question really is - ***is there any way to log the log-outs*** of users in a similar way?

Comment: Perhaps you have an XY problem?  Why do you need to know the logouts?

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/audit-logons-with-extended-events

Comment: @MitchWheat it was a requirement for some project from the higher-ups.

Comment: sounds like a time and motion study!

Comment: @Danieboy Maybe is was a requirement from the higher ups, but that doesn’t explain why they want it. Don’t be afraid to ask what problem they’re trying to solve. Sometimes higher ups come with solutions for problems, without knowing alternatives.